# Console.log is executing before browser launches URL

Tags: node.js, protractor, jasmine-node

Team,

I am declaring an element as a variable like **txtSearch : element(by.xpath('//input[@type="search"]'))**, in some point I want to log the statement as

```
var clickOn = function(webElement){
webElement.click();
console.log("Successfully clicked on the " + webElement);
};
```

I am calling this function from Spec file like **clickOn (txtSearch)**

this console.log is logging the console before the statement gets executed i.e. first all the console.log statement is executing first even before URL has launched.

Please find the required details below:

Node Version: **3.10.3**
Protractor Version: **4.0.3**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is expected behavior. All your code will execute in an asynchronous way.

Comment: You definitely should upgrade nodejs. I suggest to use 7 version. Also protractorjs 5.x will not work on node js < 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to asynchronous world!

Because everything is async, to make execution order that you want, try this:

```
var clickOn = function(webElement){
    return webElement.click().then(()=> {
        console.log("Successfully clicked on the " + webElement);
    });
};
```

This would schedule console log only when click was actually done on browser side.

But i strongly suggest to read about promises and control flow in webdriverjs:
http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html

Comment: Hmm I also wanted to post this answer, but it boggles me the fact that he uses node  3.10.3  which do not support Promises and ES6 stuff, and also where did he get this version :D?